# Sound plays several times upon collision

Tags: c#, unity, sound

Upon collision, my sound effect plays several times. How can I fix this?

```
public Sprite charAlive, charDead;
public AudioClip popAudio;

void  OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D col ){

    if (col.gameObject.name == "dirtWalls") {
        gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = charDead;
        AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(popAudio, transform.position);
        StartCoroutine (Dead ());
    }
    if (col.gameObject.name == "gooWalls") {
        gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = charDead;
        StartCoroutine (Dead ());
    }
    if (col.gameObject.name == "grassWalls") {
        gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = charDead;
        StartCoroutine (Dead ());
    }
}

IEnumerator Dead() {
//      AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(popAudio, transform.position); // PLAYS SEVERAL TIMES
//      AudioSource.mute(popAudio);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3/2);
            Application.LoadLevel ("untitled");
    // LOAD LEVEL RESETS EVERYTHING, MAKE LOAD CHAR INSTEAD?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was as easy as adding this to my IEnumerator Dead:

```
 if(hasPlayed == false){
        audio.PlayOneShot(popAudio);
        hasPlayed = true;
    }
```